# How to set text position to bottom in textField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield

I created a textField through code using the following code

```
UITextField *txtObj=[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(88,100,80,33)];
```

I am getting the textfield as i planned, but the text we type in that text field seems to appear in the top area of text but not in bottom.I tried to align it but i got tired. Can anyone tell me what's the solution

Answer (score 12, accepted):

it should be:

```
txtObj.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentBottom;
```

This property is inherited from the UIControl class. The default is: UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentTop ,  that's why you get the text on top.

Comment: You're welcome. You should accept the right answer so that the question is marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
txtObj.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentBottom;
```

If you want the text to be in the center you can use ,

```
txtObj.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4,5 solution:

```
txtObj.contentVerticalAlignment =  .bottom
```