# UITextField start text from top when height is increased

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

I have increased the height of `UITextField`. The problem is that although height is increased, the text still starts from center of textFeild. But I want text to appear from top of `UITextField`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you can use this...

```
textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentTop;
```

Comment: Anyone know how to do this in Xcode 8 / iOS 10?  It looks like UITextField contentVerticalAlignment is no longer available.

Comment: Swift 4 and 5 solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61193851/11543623

Answer (score 4):

`textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.top`

The above code has worked for me. I am using Xcode 9. Hope it works for you !

Answer (score 1):

### Swift 4 / 5

textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControl.ContentVerticalAlignment.top

Answer (score 0):

Go to Storyboard and select your UITextfield, tap **Attributes inspector**[image]

Find out **Control** section and tap **top** at vertical alignment[image]